# Question in Differential Equation (How to proceed?)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

By using the substitution $y=vs$, show that the general solution of the first order homogeneous differential equation $(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx}=y-x$ in the case where $x>0$ is given $\tan ^{-1}\frac{y}{x}+\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=k$, where k is a constant.

My attempt, 
$$(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx}=y-x$$

Let $y=xv$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$

$$(x+xv)(x\frac{dv}{dx}+v)=-x+xv$$

$$x(x\frac{dv}{dx}+v)(v+1)=x(v-1)$$

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{-v^2-1}{x(v+1)}$$

$$\frac{\frac{dv}{dx}(v+1)}{-v^2-1}=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\int \frac{\frac{dv}{dx}(v+1)}{-v^2-1}dx=\int \frac{1}{x}dx$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln (v^2+1)-\arctan(v)=\ln (x)+c_1$$
How to proceed?

Comment: Please use $\arctan$ for the inverse tangens, you don't use $\exp^{-1}$ for $\ln$ or vice versa.

Comment: a different change of variable is $x = r \cos \theta, \, y = r \sin \theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your left hand side is

$$-\int \frac{v}{v^2+1} dv - \int \frac{1}{v^2+1} dv$$

The first term can be solved by substitution. The second is $\arctan{v}$.

Comment: I've edited the post. How to substitute the k into it? @kittyL

Comment: I believe the $k$ is just your $c_1$. And you can combine the two $ln$'s using logarithmic properties.

Comment: Then what's the answer for this question? @KittyL

Comment: Didn't you already give the answer at the beginning?

Comment: That's the question. I don't know .

Comment: It is correct. If the problem says "Show that....", it should be correct.